# How can I use regex to compare a list of words with another list of words and print the matches?

Tags: python, regex, compare

How can I use regex to compare a list of words with another list of words and print the matches?

I have a list of keywords:

```
test_keywords=["buy house in kings landing", 
               "house price kings landing", 
               "cost of living kings landing", 
               "wildfire pricing"]
```

I have another list with keywords:

```
i_transactional = ["buy", "Buy", "price", "Price", "cost", "Cost", "pricing", "Pricing", "cheap", "Cheap"]
```

I would like to use the regex module to find the words in i_transactional in test_keywords.

I have this working in a construction in which I manually enter the keywords from i_transactional in a re.compile:

```
# create a regex
r_t = re.compile (r'buy|Buy|price|Price|cost|Cost|pricing|Pricing|cheap|Cheap')

# use list to find the regex words in the test_keywords list
o_t = list(filter(r_t.findall, test_keywords))

# print the results of the regex lookup
print("Transactional (", len(o_t), ") = ", o_t)
```

Output:

> Transactional ( 5 ) =  ['buy house in kings landing', 'house price kings landing', 'cost of living kings landing', 'wildfire pricing']

But instead of manually entering the words in the regex, I would like that r_t uses the i_transactional list.

I've tried it in the construction below but this doesn't work.

```
# create a regex
r_tl = re.compile(r"\<i_transactional>") #transactional

# use list to find the regex words in the test_keywords list
o_tl = list(filter(r_tl.findall, test_keywords))

# print the results of the regex lookup
print("Transactional (", len(o_tl), ") = ", o_tl)
```

There's something wrong with this code.

Output:

> Transactional ( 0 ) =  []

How can I use regex to compare a list of words with another list of words and print the matches?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string.join to join the list by `|` and create a regex.

`r_t = re.compile ('|'.join(i_transactional))`